# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onSnapshot')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im am trying to collect data from firebase database but get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onSnapshot')'

Feed.js

```
    const Feed = ({profilePic, message, timestamp, username, image}) => {
    const [posts, setPosts]  =useState([]);
    //realtime database connection
     useEffect(() => {
     db.collection['posts'].onSnapshot(snapshot => (
    setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })))
   ));
    }, []);

   return (
```

Firebase.js

```
  import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
  import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

 //initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 //database
 const db = firebase.firestore();
 export default db;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `collection` is a method, not an array. So:

```
db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(...
          //
```